# Getting below error in elastic search rest high level client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, resthighlevelclient

I am getting below error when i try to create the mapping using create index request.

> Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Failed
>   to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported
>   parameters:  [recommendations :
>   {recommendations={properties={events={type=nested,
>   properties={recommendationData={type=nested,
>   properties={recommendations={type=nested,
>   properties={recommendationType={type=keyword}}}}}}}}}}]]

and the mapping is

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "recommendations": {
      "properties": {
        "events": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "recommendationData": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "recommendations": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                    "recommendationType": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the java code is

```
private void checkAndCreateDocumentMapping() throws IOException {

        CreateIndexRequest createIndexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest(this.getIndexName());
        String indexString = getStringFromFile("nested" + ".mapping");
        createIndexRequest.source(indexString, XContentType.JSON);
        client.indices().create(createIndexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    }
```

Comment: Which elasticsearch version are you using? What does `recommendations` represent in mapping?

Comment: i'm using 7.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that elasticsearch no more support multiple mappings therefore it is no more required to pass mapping name. Assuming `recommendations` is name of mapping, it can be instead used as name of index. Therefore correct dsl to create index should be,

```
PUT recommendations
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "events": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "recommendationData": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "recommendations": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                  "recommendationType": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are correct recommendations is the mapping type but if i remove it will throw another exception

Comment: ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: No type specified for field [properties]]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=No type specified for field [properties]]];

Comment: You seems to be using older client. Make sure the client version matches the elastisearch version

Comment: it's not me.. for me issue is fixed your answer is correct  i am supposed to use older version.